# Using ROS message and python to update text input field in kivy GUI

Tags: ros, python, gui, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to design a GUI to handle stepper motors via ROS, kivy and python. You can find a minimal version of the GUI below.
Actually I want to use a ROS message to update a kivy text input field (read only).
In the minimal example, pressing the button should transfer the data of the first input field over a local ROS node to the second input field.
Actually it seems, that the Callback within the rospy.Subscriber() doesn't enter the Test class.

Thank You for any suggestions!

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Test(BoxLayout):
    text_is = 'text before button press'

    def Pub(self):
        publish = self.ids.test_text_pub.text
        try:
            ROSNode.new_text_is.publish(publish)
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass

class ROSNode(Widget):

    def Callback(publish):
        print(publish.data) #check if Callback has been called
        test.text_is = publish.data

    new_text_is = rospy.Publisher('new_text_is', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber('new_text_is', String, Callback)

    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0

<test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            id: test_button
            text: 'publish'
            on_press: root.Pub()

        TextInput:
            id: test_text_pub
            text: 'text after button press'

        TextInput:
            id: test_text_sub
            text: root.text_is
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174905/using-ros-message-and-python-to-update-text-input-field-in-kivy-gui/) by [Hozer](https://answers.ros.org/users/18996/hozer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You can use this file as an example to help you:

https://github.com/RoboEvangelist/br_control/blob/master/scripts/br_single_control.py

---

Originally posted by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) with karma: 803 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0